# mouse over sliding up div with additional information - how to?

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

On http://snapguide.com when you mouse over an image, an additional div slides up with more content.

I was wondering, is there any easy way to achieve this effect ...or maybe there's even a jQuery plugin or how-to tutorial that anyone knows about? I tried to look at the source code of the website but it's a bit beyond my comprehension as to what exactly triggers the effect.

I tried searching on Google but don't know what exactly the effect is called, so I'm a bit lost. Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Just handle `mouseenter` and show an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a code of this kind :

```
$(el).css({position: 'relative'})

$(el).hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({position: 'relative', top: '-20px'}, 1000)
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({position: '', top: ''}, 1000)
})
```

Have a look to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lulu3030/h5hGM/1/) to see the render.